# Use Jest to test appendfilesync

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to write a test for appendfilesync. I call this when using a logger and so I have 1 line of code not covered. Here is the code (note: using tslog for logger)

```
export function logToTransport(logObject: ILogObject) {
  appendFileSync('monopoly_deal.log', JSON.stringify(logObject) + '\n');
}
```

I've tried mocking up 'fs' which can work so that nothing actually writes to file but I don't actually test the writing. Here is start of my test code to set things up:

```
const log: Logger = new Logger({ name: 'card_types_test' });
    log.attachTransport(
      {
        silly: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        debug: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        trace: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        info: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        warn: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        error: CardTypes.logToTransport,
        fatal: CardTypes.logToTransport,
      },
      'info',
    );

// Here I would need to setup a jest.spyon I think to intercept the call but not sure how to do it. Something like const spy = jest.fn(CardTypes.logToTransport);

log.info('test'); // Logs to file
expect(spy).toequal({object with my data}); // I didn't put what object would actually look like for brevity.
```

Any guidance on how to mock up writing to files is greatly appreciated along with any other critiques (still a junior level programmer at best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the code logic of `logToTransport` function rather than `fs.appendFileSync` method. `fs.appendFileSync` is a built-in method of Node.js and it's well tested.

You can only mock the `fs.appendFileSync` method, this way is called [mocking partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials). We are going to test the implementation detail of `logToTransport` function, this test strategy is called [white-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing).

Besides, we can use `jest.isMockFunction` to verify if we do the mocking partials successfully.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { appendFileSync } from 'fs';

type ILogObject = any;
export function logToTransport(logObject: ILogObject) {
  appendFileSync('monopoly_deal.log', JSON.stringify(logObject) + '\n');
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { logToTransport } from '.';

jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('fs') as typeof fs),
  appendFileSync: jest.fn(),
}));
describe('73466276', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(fs.appendFileSync)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(fs.appendFile)).toBeFalsy();
    logToTransport({ level: 'debug', payload: { name: 'teresa teng' } });
    expect(fs.appendFileSync).toBeCalledWith(
      'monopoly_deal.log',
      JSON.stringify({ level: 'debug', payload: { name: 'teresa teng' } }) + '\n'
    );
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73466276/index.test.ts (11.306 s)
  73466276
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.012 s
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Appreciate the explanation as what you stated was my end goal.